# Ookii.Dialogs ProgressDialog in modal style doesn't focus owner window after completion

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, dialog

I'm using the Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf.ProgressDialog (see http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/ for binaries and source) to visualize a certain process. It is a combination of a BackgroundWorker and a native API call to the Windows XP+ integrated ProgressDialog. I am using the Dialog like this:

```
this.worker = new ProgressDialog {ShowTimeRemaining = true};
this.model.BackgroundWorker = this.worker;
this.worker.DoWork += (s, ev) => this.model.ExportAnalysis(saveFileName);
this.worker.ShowDialog(this);
```

After the task is done the modal dialog should refocus the owner window (`ShowDialog(this)`, `this` is a WPF `Window`). But instead it focuses a random window currently open. After some inspection of the Ookii.Dialogs code I found out that the native Windows API call `IOperationsProgressDialog::StartProgressDialog` is being used. The API call is wrapped like this in the Ookii.Dialogs C# source:

```
[PreserveSig]
void StartProgressDialog(
    IntPtr hwndParent,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]
    object punkEnableModless,
    ProgressDialogFlags dwFlags,
    IntPtr pvResevered
    );
```

After some research I encountered two posts on this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775262%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. Gideon7 mentions this:

> [...] PROGDLG_MODAL should be considered broken and its use avoided. [...]

This post from 2008 and also in the newer post from 2014 it says this feature is broken. So my question: Did anyone encounter a similar problem and had a chance to fix it? Or am I just using the dialog wrong? Has anyone advice how I could fix this, because Microsoft apparently didn't fix anything yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to force the window back to being active after the `ShowDialog(this)` call.

```
this.worker.ShowDialog(this);
this.Activate();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.activate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you! I was again thinking in a too complex way :) Nice hack that works. But because of the BackgroundWorker it works only on the RunWorkerCompleted event, so I added this line of code `this.worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, ev) => this.Activate();`